# Generate API client from Django REST framework API

Tags: django, rest, orm, django-rest-framework

I have an website in Django that is using the REST framework to provide an API.

Is there a way to generate an API client that can be used to communicate with this API that provides objects mapping the contents of the API?

Comment: Generate an API client ? If you want to communicate with your APIs, you could try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (chrome extension).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a javascript client API, I have a django management task that I use to generate a javascript library from my DRF API 
using AngularJS 1.*.  I'm still using DRF 2.4, for easy nested object writes, and Django 1.7.  [Here it is as a github gist](https://gist.github.com/RossRogers/aa0f3489383575a3fe414c0749a26d2a)

Take that file, stick it in `<app>/management/commands/` and call it like:

```
python manage.py rest_framework_2_js rest_api.gen.js [base_factory_name] [server_base_url]
```

If your `base_factory_name` was `foo` and you had an API object at `server_base_url/Bar/` named `Bar`, you would use it like:

```
foo.Bar.get(42)
  .then(function(bar_inst) { 
     console.log(bar_inst);
     bar_inst.baz = 77;
     bar_inst.save()
       .then(function() {
         console.log('bar_inst has been saved');
       });
  })
```

or

```
foo.BarList.get('filter_a=5&field_filter_b=abc,d')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.results);
  })
```

Each instance in the `data.result` will be a `foo.Bar` instance.

You can add callbacks before sending to the server and after retrieving from the server using  `foo.Bar.pre_save(function (inst) {/*callback mutator*/})` and `foo.Bar.post_restore( function(inst) { /*callback mutator*/})`.

Anyways, this management task is not productized and it has only one user - me, but I have been using it for 2 years and it works great for me :-)  We can work to get it working in your configuration if you like.  Naturally the biggest caveat is the AngularJS 1.* dependency.